# PostgreSQL slow query with Ranking result

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.8. IN table `products` I have 335198 rows, looks like not many, I ecpect maybe 2 millions. Some configuration `postgres -c work_mem=100MB -c max_parallel_workers_per_gather=6 -c max_connections=300`
And I want Ranking Search Results but I have grouping result data.

```
            create index npdbcs_swedish_custom_index on products
                using GIN(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', name||price||description||brand))
```

Now my query spent 62 second :( not good. Without Ranking **2.2** second this is great result, GIN index works correct. How to correct apply Ranking for my query, help please

if I correct understand many time spent by `ts_rank_cd` and  `ORDER BY rank`, I had the same conclusion when commented `ts_rank_cd` in select and `ORDER BY runk` and had 2 second spent time

**UPDATE**
Thank you @jjanes I changed `to_tsvector` logic and now I saved this data in separate column. This is my function with trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsvectorupdate ON products;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS products_ts_trigger;
CREATE FUNCTION products_ts_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.common_fts :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.name,'')), 'A') ||     
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.description,'')), 'B') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.price::text,'')), 'C') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.brand,'')), 'D');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON products FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION products_ts_trigger();
```

I will test seacrh perfomance tommorow. Now I have question about `price`, type `numeric    10  2`, correct cast it to text ?

this what I got from test product

```
'1595.00':6C 'black':5A 'bärsel':2A 'matt':4A 'najell':1A,7 'original':3A
```

**UPDATED 19_06_20**
My test server 6 CPU and 16GB ORM
I did it for all rows (raw rows `331681` and ater grouoping by `group_identity` I had `114856` rows).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products;
331681

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
GROUP BY group_identity) as sub_s
114856
```

Created `common_fts` Added new index

```
CREATE INDEX common_ndpb_search_idx ON products USING GIN (common_fts);
```

set `work_mem` = 2GB(instead 200mb) and diff in result 61.5s(without `common_fts`) and 49.2s (with `common_fts`) - great perfomance but not enough.

set on `track_io_timing` and share with you what I got in query plans

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

SELECT                         
products_alias.group_identity

,(array_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.shop))[1]::TEXT AS shop
,(array_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.shop_relation_id))[1]::INTEGER AS "shopRelationId"
,jsonb_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.extras) FILTER (WHERE products_alias.extras IS NOT NULL) AS extras

,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.brand::text)) AS "storeBrand"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.currency::text)) AS "storeCurrency"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.price::text)) AS "storePrice"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::TEXT), array_agg(products_alias.image_url)) AS "storeImageUrl"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::TEXT), array_agg(products_alias.name)) AS "storeNames"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.extras::text)) AS "storeExtras"

,COUNT(DISTINCT uip.id) as "numberOfEntries"
,SUM(ts_rank_cd(products_alias.common_fts, to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish',
'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*'))) AS rank                                 


FROM products products_alias 

LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN product_category cp on cp.product_id = products_alias.id                              

WHERE products_alias.common_fts @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*')                      

GROUP BY products_alias.group_identity 
ORDER BY 
rank DESC,
"numberOfEntries" DESC  
LIMIT 20

Limit  (cost=146327.93..146327.98 rows=20 width=286) (actual time=49668.929..49668.937 rows=20 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=164403 read=50594
  ->  Sort  (cost=146327.93..146455.42 rows=50997 width=286) (actual time=49668.928..49668.933 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (sum(ts_rank_cd(products_alias.common_fts, '''yard'':* | ''subskjort'':* | ''skjort'':* | ''barn'':* | ''ebb'':* | ''överdel'':* | ''barn'':*'::tsquery))) DESC, (count(DISTINCT uip.id)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 490kB
        Buffers: shared hit=164403 read=50594
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=110836.74..144970.91 rows=50997 width=286) (actual time=1482.836..49612.157 rows=28329 loops=1)
              Group Key: products_alias.group_identity
              Buffers: shared hit=164403 read=50594
              ->  Sort  (cost=110836.74..111696.38 rows=343854 width=623) (actual time=1482.182..1596.263 rows=191570 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: products_alias.group_identity
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 180138kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=39 read=44477
                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=61681.49..79216.90 rows=343854 width=623) (actual time=500.548..901.555 rows=191570 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (products_alias.id = uip.products_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=39 read=44477
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=61668.34..77912.84 rows=343854 width=619) (actual time=500.525..850.976 rows=191570 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (cp.product_id = products_alias.id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=39 read=44477
                                ->  Seq Scan on product_category cp  (cost=0.00..14000.49 rows=854849 width=4) (actual time=0.024..109.998 rows=838650 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared read=5452
                                ->  Hash  (cost=60000.65..60000.65 rows=133415 width=619) (actual time=498.826..498.826 rows=76368 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 50274kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=39 read=39025
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products products_alias  (cost=1405.97..60000.65 rows=133415 width=619) (actual time=93.217..410.644 rows=76368 loops=1)
                                            Recheck Cond: (common_fts @@ '''yard'':* | ''subskjort'':* | ''skjort'':* | ''barn'':* | ''ebb'':* | ''överdel'':* | ''barn'':*'::tsquery)
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=38977
                                            Buffers: shared hit=39 read=39025
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on common_ndpb_search_idx  (cost=0.00..1372.61 rows=133415 width=0) (actual time=84.859..84.859 rows=76368 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (common_fts @@ '''yard'':* | ''subskjort'':* | ''skjort'':* | ''barn'':* | ''ebb'':* | ''överdel'':* | ''barn'':*'::tsquery)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=39 read=48
                          ->  Hash  (cost=11.40..11.40 rows=140 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on user_ip_product uip  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.824 ms
Execution Time: 49683.687 ms
```

and without ranking

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

SELECT                         
products_alias.group_identity

,(array_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.shop))[1]::TEXT AS shop
,(array_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.shop_relation_id))[1]::INTEGER AS "shopRelationId"
,jsonb_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.extras) FILTER (WHERE products_alias.extras IS NOT NULL) AS extras

,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.brand::text)) AS "storeBrand"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.currency::text)) AS "storeCurrency"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.price::text)) AS "storePrice"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::TEXT), array_agg(products_alias.image_url)) AS "storeImageUrl"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::TEXT), array_agg(products_alias.name)) AS "storeNames"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.extras::text)) AS "storeExtras"

,COUNT(DISTINCT uip.id) as "numberOfEntries"



FROM products products_alias 

LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN product_category cp on cp.product_id = products_alias.id                              

WHERE products_alias.common_fts @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*')                      

GROUP BY products_alias.group_identity 

LIMIT 20

    Limit  (cost=0.99..180.91 rows=20 width=282) (actual time=0.098..1.912 rows=20 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=577
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.99..438439.05 rows=48737 width=282) (actual time=0.097..1.905 rows=20 loops=1)
        Group Key: products_alias.group_identity
        Buffers: shared hit=577
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.99..408316.57 rows=328199 width=260) (actual time=0.042..1.294 rows=107 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=577
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.57..309213.08 rows=127214 width=260) (actual time=0.032..1.054 rows=36 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=432
                    ->  Index Scan using group_identity on products products_alias  (cost=0.42..287224.67 rows=127214 width=256) (actual time=0.026..0.996 rows=36 loops=1)
                          Filter: (common_fts @@ '''yard'':* | ''subskjort'':* | ''skjort'':* | ''barn'':* | ''ebb'':* | ''överdel'':* | ''barn'':*'::tsquery)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 327
                          Buffers: shared hit=396
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_5b9c784c6c8a81a9 on user_ip_product uip  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=36)
                          Index Cond: (products_id = products_alias.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=36
              ->  Index Only Scan using idx_cdfc73564584665a on product_category cp  (cost=0.42..0.74 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=3 loops=36)
                    Index Cond: (product_id = products_alias.id)
                    Heap Fetches: 107
                    Buffers: shared hit=145
Planning Time: 0.612 ms
Execution Time: 2.015 ms
```

Any idea what I can do more for optimization query if it's possible?

**UPDATE**

After spent many time searching and analysis I nade decision replace `ts_rank_cd` to `ts_rank`, and after spent time decreased for request to ***3.7s***

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

SELECT                         
products_alias.group_identity

,(array_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.shop))[1]::TEXT AS shop
,(array_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.shop_relation_id))[1]::INTEGER AS "shopRelationId"
,jsonb_agg(DISTINCT products_alias.extras) FILTER (WHERE products_alias.extras IS NOT NULL) AS extras

,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.brand::text)) AS "storeBrand"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.currency::text)) AS "storeCurrency"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.price::text)) AS "storePrice"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::TEXT), array_agg(products_alias.image_url)) AS "storeImageUrl"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::TEXT), array_agg(products_alias.name)) AS "storeNames"
,hstore(array_agg(products_alias.id::text), array_agg(products_alias.extras::text)) AS "storeExtras"

,COUNT(DISTINCT uip.id) as "numberOfEntries"
,SUM(ts_rank(products_alias.common_fts, to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish',
'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*'))) AS rank                                 


FROM products products_alias 

LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN product_category cp on cp.product_id = products_alias.id                              

WHERE products_alias.common_fts @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*')                      

GROUP BY products_alias.group_identity 
ORDER BY 
rank DESC
--products_alias.price DESC  
LIMIT 20

   Limit  (cost=154665.62..154665.67 rows=20 width=286) (actual time=3661.952..3661.959 rows=20 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=302308 read=64079
  ->  Sort  (cost=154665.62..154787.47 rows=48737 width=286) (actual time=3661.950..3661.955 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (sum(ts_rank(products_alias.common_fts, '''yard'':* | ''subskjort'':* | ''skjort'':* | ''barn'':* | ''ebb'':* | ''överdel'':* | ''barn'':*'::tsquery))) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 476kB
        Buffers: shared hit=302308 read=64079
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=120784.78..153368.75 rows=48737 width=286) (actual time=1840.274..3632.377 rows=28332 loops=1)
              Group Key: products_alias.group_identity
              Buffers: shared hit=302308 read=64079
              ->  Sort  (cost=120784.78..121605.27 rows=328199 width=615) (actual time=1840.182..1888.089 rows=192241 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: products_alias.group_identity
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 180793kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=131456 read=64079
                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=73238.20..90714.84 rows=328199 width=615) (actual time=922.587..1314.311 rows=192241 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (products_alias.id = uip.products_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=131456 read=64079
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=73225.05..89469.55 rows=328199 width=611) (actual time=922.572..1267.515 rows=192241 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (cp.product_id = products_alias.id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=131456 read=64079
                                ->  Seq Scan on product_category cp  (cost=0.00..14000.49 rows=854849 width=4) (actual time=0.011..100.653 rows=842342 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=212 read=5240
                                ->  Hash  (cost=71634.88..71634.88 rows=127214 width=611) (actual time=921.793..921.794 rows=76553 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49374kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=131244 read=58839
                                      ->  Seq Scan on products products_alias  (cost=0.00..71634.88 rows=127214 width=611) (actual time=0.096..839.409 rows=76553 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (common_fts @@ '''yard'':* | ''subskjort'':* | ''skjort'':* | ''barn'':* | ''ebb'':* | ''överdel'':* | ''barn'':*'::tsquery)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 256160
                                            Buffers: shared hit=131244 read=58839
                          ->  Hash  (cost=11.40..11.40 rows=140 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on user_ip_product uip  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.906 ms
Execution Time: 3677.207 ms
```

Now my main question how much different function `ts_rank` and `ts_rank_cd`(I read official doc) could someone explain by simple expression about differents?

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061932/how-to-optimize-query-if-i-already-use-gin-index ?  Did you ever get track_io_timing turned on?

Comment: @jjanes thank you, I updated my question. At this moment my query looks little bit different and more complicated lke before, I had to add `hstore` and grouping by `identity_group`

Comment: @jjanes if I correct understand many time spent by `ts_rank_cd` and  `ORDER BY rank`, I had the same conclusion when commented `ts_rank_cd` in select and `ORDER BY runk` and had 2 second spent time

Comment: @Laurenz Albe could you please look in it ?

Comment: @jjanes `One thing that might make it faster is if you save the computed tsvector into the table as a real column, rather than computing it dynamically` hot it's should looks ? Could you give me some example plesae ?

Comment: @jjanes aaaa, I unerstand, need will save `to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', 'a fat  cat sat on a mat - it ate a fat rats');` in separate column and then just `CREATE INDEX my_textsearch_idx ON products USING GIN (column_for_ts_vector_data);` and then `SUM(ts_rank_cd(column_for_ts_vector_data, to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish',
'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*'))) AS rank` and `WHERE column_for_ts_vector_data @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'Yard:*|subSkjortor:*|Skjortor:*|Barn:*|ebbe:*|ÖVERDELAR:*|till:*|barn:*')` I will test it and will share

Comment: You can use tsvector_update_trigger (from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS) to keep the tsvector column in sync with the raw text columns for future changes.  But you would have to do a bulk update to get the existing data in sync to start with.

Comment: @jjanes Thank you answer and I updated my question. Could you look please price column with numeric type, correct if I cast it to text ?

Comment: Yes, casting price to text should work, but it seems strange to me you want to search on price in the same way you search on those other fields.  Also, you aren't currently using setweight, so I wouldn't think you want to start using it in the trigger, unless you have changed your mind about it.

Comment: Example some common input for searching by some words and if user want search by price too why not. About weight I added it in trigger for generating ts vector. If word matching with word from name product should be has more weight instead product where this word present in description. I will test how its will works.

Comment: @jjanes time shortened on 12seconds, great perfomance. But not enough. Whould be great if it will be 10 second. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of your execution time is spent doing the `GroupAggregate`.

That probably means that PostgreSQL spends much time calculating the aggregate functions or `ts_rank`. You could try to verify that with a version of the query that uses fewer aggregate functions – see if that is faster.

If I am right, there is not much you can do to make this faster.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will aply it after refactor ts vector to separate column, like adviced jjanes

Comment: I set 2GB instead 200mb on test server, but it did not affect the time :( I update my question

Comment: Hm. No execution plan.

Comment: I added it in query `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and add query plan after query. Or what you mean? Describe me please what need to do for more depth analysis and I wil do that

Comment: I increased `work_mem` to 4GB, but still faced with `Sort + GroupAggregate` ... Any idea?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. See my updated answer. I cannot think of anything to speed this up.

Comment: problem with ranking I'm sure about that on 100%, becasue without ranking 2 =secons spent time. Main question how to optimization `ts_rank_cd`

Comment: I faced with wondering result 3.7s after replace `ts_rank_cd` to `ts_rank`. I updated my question